# nix: referencing one local perl package from another

Tags: perl, nix, nixos

I'm trying to build a local perl package that uses another as a dependency.

The dependency in question is [`Getopt-Plus`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Plus); it is installed using this nix expression:

```
{ fetchurl, perlPackages }:

perlPackages.buildPerlModule rec {
  version = "0.99";
  name = "Getopt-Plus";

  src = fetchurl {
    url = "mirror://cpan/authors/id/F/FL/FLUFFY/${name}-${version}.tar.gz";
    sha256 = "0vsr4d0myv98aqbs7rc5rvqdpfz1vg1w7b5wyn4i6lmycp1wxxqk";
  };

  buildInputs = [ ];
  propagatedBuildInputs = with perlPackages; [ ];

  doCheck = false;
}
```

That installation succeeds just fine, as evidenced thus:

```
$ nix-env -q | grep Getopt
perl5.28.2-Getopt-Plus-0.99
```

Now, I have a local package, excitingly called `Finance`, that uses Getopt-Plus.  So here is a putative nix expression:

```
{ nixpkgs }:

with nixpkgs;
with perlPackages;
buildPerlModule rec {
  version = "1.01";
  name = "Finance";

  src = fetchurl {
    url = "http://localhost:8888/${name}-${version}-002.tar.gz";
    sha256 = "0fib0rbzx8519imsw9jrfl805r6lrl6qzbnhipxxix5scar913r7";
  };

  buildInputs = [ ];
  propagatedBuildInputs = [ "Getopt-Plus" ];

  doCheck = false;
}
```

Along with an overlay file, to allow for references to locally-defined packages (via `self`):

```
self: super: {
  Finance = import ../pkgs/Finance/default.nix { nixpkgs = self; };
}
```

My problem is, how to refer to Getopt-Plus; everything I try leads to an error of the form `build input Getopt-Plus does not exist`.

I have tried with- and without- double-quotes (without quotes leads to "undefined variable" errors; clearly it thinks that `Getopt-Plus` would be a variable, I guess because of the hyphen); I have tried the "installed" name of `perl5.28.2-Getopt-Plus-0.99`; I have tried other variations on these (e.g., `perl5.28.2-Getopt-Plus`, `perl-Getopt-Plus`, `perl-Getopt-Plus-0.99`.  I also tried removing the hyphen from the Getopt-Plus installation to become `GetoptPlus`; it installs fine by itself, of course, but doesn't seem to help this problem.

If I fire up nix repl, setting `p = import <nixpkgs> {}`; then it clearly presents `p.GetoptPlus` (and `p.Finance`) as a valid derivation.

My questions are:

1. What is the correct name to use to allow Finance to depend upon Getopt-Plus; and
2. Should I be using buildInputs or propagatedBuildInputs here?  I am unclear on the difference.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I checked a Nix Perl module package which has a dependency on another Perl module (DBD-SQLite) and it suggests that you need to add the dependency (ex. `GetoptPlus` to your function arguments (along with the `nixpkgs` you already have) and then add it to `propagatedBuildInputs` unquoted. See here: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/development/perl-modules/DBD-SQLite/default.nix

Comment: Aha!  Thank you @EmmanuelRosa, you are absolutely right, that works.  And what's more, it led me to a better solution still; I was missing an overlay for GetoptPlus - as soon as I include that, GetoptPlus appers in `nixpkgs`, and thus I don't need an explicit import at all.  Bonza!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an overlay pointing to GetoptPlus makes it available in nixpkgs, and my problem is solved:

```
self: super: {
  Getopt-Plus = import ../pkgs/Getopt-Plus/default.nix { nixpkgs = self; };
}
```